# std::move whole range-expression in range-based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, move, move-semantics

In GitHub repositories there are not few examples where the range-expression in range-based for loop is surrounded in `std::move`, e.g. in [pytorch](https://github.com/aixoss/pytorch/blob/642e14a2ecc20bfdd718fcc3a7c7274ec76e3961/caffe2/core/c10_operator.h#L72):

```cpp
...
outputs = (*call_op)(schema, std::move(inputs), std::move(outputs));

for (auto&& output : std::move(outputs)) {
   torch::jit::push(*stack, std::move(output));
}
```

Since `output` here just iterates over the elements of `std::move(outputs)` and we have `std::move(output)` inside loop body, does for-loop is really different from the variant without the first `std::move`:

```cpp
for (auto&& output : outputs) {
   torch::jit::push(*stack, std::move(output));
}
```

and if yes, can the difference be observed with some classes from the standard library or only with some specially designed ones?

Comment: the move seems superfluous to me.  The element that gets bound to `auto&& output` is `*__begin` where `__begin` is retrieved from a begin expression on a reference to the range so that should be considering the range as an lvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range-based `for` statement is [defined](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1.sentence-1) by translation:

```cpp
{
   init-statement_opt
   auto &&range = for-range-initializer ;
   auto begin = begin-expr ;
   auto end = end-expr ;
   for ( ; begin != end; ++begin ) {
      for-range-declaration = * begin ;
      statement
   }
}
```

where `begin-expr` and `end-expr` either are `range.begin()` and `range.end()`, or are `begin(range)` and `end(range)`, dependent on whether lookup for the former succeeds.

This means that within `begin-expr` and `end-expr`, `range` is an lvalue, regardless of whether `for-range-initializer` is an lvalue or an xvalue (or even a prvalue).

So wrapping a `for-range-initializer` in `std::move()` will not have any effect on program behavior.